# SQL not returning values where null in another table

Tags: sql, join, select, group-by

I'm trying to use the SQL join function to grab information from multiple tables.

My issue is I can't seem to get the desired result.

```
     select a.DRINKER, sum(C.PRICE)
     from DRINKERS a
     left join ORDERS b on a.DRINKER = b.DRINKER
     join SERVES c on b.PUB = c.PUB and d.DRINK = c.DRINK
     group by a.DRINKER;
```

This gives the following results

```
----------------------
|DRINKER|sum(C.PRICE)|
----------------------
|  BOB  |   200.10   |
|  NED  |   172.50   |
|  JOE  |   270.90   |
|  TIM  |    80.10   |
----------------------
```

However I want this to be giving all of the people in a.DRINKER like such:

```
----------------------
|DRINKER|sum(C.PRICE)|
----------------------
|  BOB  |   200.10   |
|  NED  |   172.50   |
|  JOE  |   270.90   |
|  TIM  |    80.10   |
|  PAT  |    null    |
|  ANN  |    null    |
----------------------
```

Any guidance would be appreciated and if you could also explain the logic behind the changes that would be greatly appreciated as I wanna learn what I should be doing! Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. Isolate the first erroneous subexpression & its input & output. (Debugging fundamental.) PS That's not code you ran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you got a left join between DRINKERS and ORDERS, the join between ORDERS and SERVES, will filter out any nulls obtained in the first left join.

To fix this you could try by further left joining the tables

```
 select a.DRINKER, sum(C.PRICE)
   from DRINKERS a
   left join ORDERS b on a.DRINKER = b.DRINKER
   left join SERVES c on b.PUB = c.PUB and d.DRINK = c.DRINK
  group by a.DRINKER;
```

Comment: You should use table aliases that are abbreviations for the table names.  Meaningless aliases such as `a`, `b`, and `c` just make queries hard to understand.

Comment: In general i would do that for a production system, for testing purposes i would use simple variables/names just as x,y,z in an equation